# Passing JSON to Python script via AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json

What's the ideal way to pass a large JSON data object from Javascript through AJAX to a Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using some web framework? [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/) has pretty decent support for JSON decoding/encoding.

Comment: Perfect, Django is exactly what I needed.